# Why does Remix.run not pick up server file changes and I need to reload the server manually? (There are times that I need to rebuild)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I'm following a modular DDD approach in my Remix project (Currently version 1.15.0).

I extract all the backend logic into Commands and Queries, which are then exposed through a mediator pattern in a file called "register.server.ts" (Everything lies inside the `server` folder)

See:

[image]

Everything works. The only problem is that every time I make a change in development while I have the dev build server running, it doesn't detect any changes.

Additionally, there are times in which I need to run `dev:build` and `build` manually to detect the changes.

Why is that?

I can't find any documentation whatsoever, and appending the files with `.server.ts` makes no difference.

Here's my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "edge-remix",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "run-s build:*",
    "build:css": "npm run generate:css -- --minify",
    "build:remix": "remix build",
    "build:server": "esbuild --platform=node --format=cjs ./server.ts --outdir=build --bundle",
    "dev": "run-p dev:*",
    "dev:build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run build:server -- --watch",
    "dev:css": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run generate:css -- --watch",
    "dev:remix": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development remix watch",
    "dev:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --inspect --require ./node_modules/dotenv/config --require ./mocks -r tsconfig-paths/register ./build/server.js",
    "docker": "docker-compose up -d",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "generate:css": "tailwindcss -o ./app/styles/tailwind.css",
    "icons": "npx @svgr/cli  --out-dir  app/assets/generated/icons -- app/assets/images/icons",
    "icons:watch": "npm-watch icons",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "setup": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && prisma db seed",
    "seed": "prisma db seed",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate",
    "prisma:migrate": "prisma migrate dev",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/server.js",
    "start:mocks": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --require ./mocks --require dotenv/config --require tsconfig-paths/register ./build/server.js",
    "test": "vitest",
    "test:e2e:dev": "start-server-and-test dev http://localhost:3000 \"npx cypress open\"",
    "pretest:e2e:run": "npm run build",
    "test:e2e:run": "cross-env PORT=8811 start-server-and-test start:mocks http://localhost:8811 \"npx cypress run\"",
    "typecheck": "tsc -b && tsc -b cypress",
    "validate": "run-p \"test -- --run\" lint typecheck test:e2e:run",
    "postinstall": "patch-package && prisma generate",
    "generate-seed-profile": "ts-node ./prompts/transform-scripts/to-db-manual"
  },
  "prettier": {},
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "/node_modules",
    "/build",
    "/public/build",
    "/postgres-data"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.192.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.194.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.192.0",
    "@aws-sdk/util-endpoints": "^3.192.0",
    "@casl/ability": "^6.3.3",
    "@casl/prisma": "^1.3.3",
    "@growthbook/growthbook": "^0.21.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.11",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^7.8.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "@remix-run/express": "1.15.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "1.15.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "1.15.0",
    "@remix-run/server-runtime": "1.15.0",
    "@remix-run/vercel": "1.15.0",
    "@remix-validated-form/with-zod": "^2.0.5",
    "@sentry/remix": "^7.30.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "@vercel/remix-entry-server": "^0.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "daisyui": "^2.31.0",
    "domain-functions": "^1.5.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "http-status-codes-by-hutu": "^0.0.5",
    "i18next": "^21.9.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.5",
    "i18next-fs-backend": "^1.1.5",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.4",
    "immer": "^9.0.16",
    "isbot": "^3.5.3",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "neverthrow": "^5.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-colorful": "^5.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.38.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.6",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-image-crop": "^10.0.8",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "remix-forms": "^1.5.0",
    "remix-i18next": "^4.1.1",
    "remix-params-helper": "^0.4.10",
    "remix-utils": "^3.3.0",
    "remix-validated-form": "^4.6.7",
    "resend": "^0.16.0",
    "tiny-invariant": "^1.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "vcard-creator": "^0.5.0",
    "webp-converter-browser": "^1.0.3",
    "zod": "^3.20.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.5.0",
    "@remix-run/dev": "1.15.0",
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "1.15.0",
    "@svgr/cli": "^6.5.1",
    "@svgr/plugin-jsx": "^6.5.1",
    "@svgr/plugin-prettier": "^6.5.1",
    "@svgr/plugin-svgo": "^6.5.1",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.18.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.4.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/i18next-fs-backend": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/mime-types": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.29.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "c8": "^7.12.0",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "cypress": "^10.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.8",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "happy-dom": "^6.0.4",
    "msw": "^0.47.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.13",
    "prisma": "^4.11.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.13.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.3",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0",
    "vitest": "^0.29.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "org:seed": "ts-node --require tsconfig-paths/register --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"}  prisma/seed.ts",
    "seed": "ts-node --require tsconfig-paths/register --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"}  prisma/seed-organization.ts"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "prisma": "^4.11.0"
  }
}
```

remix.config.js

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: "./node_modules/.cache/remix",
  ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*", "**/*.css", "**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  devServerPort: 8002,
  serverBuildTarget:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "node-cjs" : "vercel",
  // When running locally in development mode, we use the built in remix
  // server. This does not understand the vercel lambda module format,
  // so we default back to the standard build output.
  server: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? undefined : "./server.js",
  // publicPath: "/build/",
  // serverBuildPath: "api/index.js",
  // serverMainFields: ["main", "module"],
  // serverModuleFormat: "cjs",
  // serverMinify: false,
  serverDependenciesToBundle: [/^validator*/, /^prisma/, /^@prisma\/client/],
  future: {
    v2_normalizeFormMethod: true,
    v2_meta: true,
    // v2_routeConvention: true,
    v2_errorBoundary: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that it did pick up the server changes.  My problem was that I was using the context to connect to my files (Through a mediator). As the main server.js file never reloads, the context isn't reloaded, and the same files are served.

Comment: Hey, I just came across your question while searching how I can configure remix express directory with server.TS file. Out of the box, it's server.JS but I need to have a server folder with .TS files in it just like your example. Any chance you have it as a template ?

Comment: @noiseymur Rename it to .ts. You should be good to go.

Comment: @jose-a Could you possibly provide an answer with an example explanation to a solution? I am facing a similar problem with my express server not hot reloading after code changes.

Comment: @jckmlczk I've seen that you added an answer. In my case, the problem was that the express instance needed to reload entirely. The CQRS object is loaded into memory, and if any of those files changes, it won't be possible for the object to detect that it has changed, hence a full reload is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In my case file changes in server code were not applied due to a change introduced to blues-stack inside https://github.com/remix-run/blues-stack/pull/221/files

All I had to do is revert changes from PR above - remove dynamic import of `chokidar` and replace `createDevRequestHandler` with a previous implementation.

Comment: no need to revert, the fix has been committed now https://github.com/remix-run/blues-stack/pull/222

Comment: Thx for the comment, but the change you mention in the link seems to be a fix to some other issue. I precisely had to remove dynamic import of chokidar in order for dev reload to work properly - I implemented my `server.ts` file based on official blues stack repo: https://github.com/remix-run/blues-stack/blob/main/server.ts